# How can I cause Eclipse to compile GWT with the -strict flag?

Tags: gwt, eclipse-plugin, compiler-warnings

I am using the GWT Eclipse plugin to develop and test a GWT appengine app.

When I run the development server, I see in the **Development** tab:

> - Validating newly compiled units
>
>   - Ignored 2 units with compilation errors
> - Module elided has been loaded.

Clicking on the middle entry shows

> ```
> [INFO] [tasx] - Ignored 2 units with compilation errors in first pass.
> Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
> ```

I don't want to ignore potential errors.  How can I cause the Eclipse plugin to pass the `-strict` flag to the GWT compiler?

Comment: I especially like using the "-localWorkers 4" parameter here to speed up my compiles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the dialog "GWT compile" open "advanced".
Now you could add compiler options

Comment: How do I find the "GWT compile" dialog?

Comment: Found it.  Right click on the project in the project view.  Google -> GWT Compile.

Answer (score 1):

You can also open the Run Configuration for your Development Mode. Then go to the GWT tab and change the log level to DEBUG or TRACE.